# Custom reduction of losses within each batch in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am using `keras` for `tensorflow` in `Python`. I have a custom loss function that returns a single number for each sample in a batch (so a vector with length = batch size). How can I also specify a custom reduction method to aggregate these sample losses into a single loss for the entire batch? Is it acceptable to include this reduction within the custom loss function and have this function return just a single scalar rather than a vector of losses?

Comment: As far as I know, it is perfectly fine to reduce the losses for all elements within the batch to a single number for the complete batch within the loss function.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your application and goal. A very common approach is to perform a reduce_mean over the loss generated on batch size. Some also use reduce_sum, which of course makes the loss value to depend on the batch size.  A general (and maybe unnecessarily complicated) approach could be to use a function to call your desired function, which reduces the batch loss to a single value. Let's call it reducer. In your loss function, in the last line, you can call it right before return:

```
class my_loss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, inputs)
        # a bunch of assignments
        self.reducer = self._get_reducer_function(inputs) (or a normal mean function)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
            y_batch = ....
            return self.reducer(y_batch)

    def get_config(self):
            return {'input': 1}
```

Of course you don't need to write so complicated, but it should give you an idea of how to do it. Also, you can simply add sample_weights if you need.